# How can I Pivot my Table and separate 'aggregated' fields with a Comma?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I would like to do a pivot of my data.

My initial Query is the following :

```
SELECT 
      pre_memberidyominame  As FullName
      ,LocalizedLabel       AS 'Role'
      ,COALESCE(pre_salesorderid,pre_opportunityid)  AS ActivityGuid

  FROM [dbo].[pre_salesteammember]    STM
  LEFT JOIN OptionSetMetadata OS
    ON STM.pre_rolecode = OS.[Option]
    AND EntityName = 'pre_salesteammember'
```

Result :

```
FullName |    Role         |   ActivityGuid
Peter     Account Manager    1
Laura     Account Manager    1
Frank     Lead BDM           2
Tom       IT Manager         2
Sander    PR Specialist      3
```

I would like the actual result to look like this :

```
Account Manager  |  Lead BDM   | ActivityGuid
Peter, Laura          NULL          1
NULL                  FRANK         2
NULL                  NULL          3   --> or could just be gone --> Last column should have Unique Values
```

I tried using PIVOT, but I cant seem to get there!
Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    max(case when localizedlabel = 'Account Manager' then pre_memberidyominame end) account_manager,
    max(case when localizedlabel = 'Lead BDM' then pre_memberidyominame end) lead_bdm,
    coalesce(pre_salesorderid,pre_opportunityid)  as activityguid
from [dbo].[pre_salesteammember] stm
left join optionsetmetadata os
    on stm.pre_rolecode = os.[option]
    and entityname = 'pre_salesteammember'  
group by coalesce(pre_salesorderid,pre_opportunityid)
```

---

If you want to aggregate the names per activity, you can use `string_agg()` instead of `max()` (available starting SQL Server 2017):

```
select
    string_agg(case when localizedlabel = 'Account Manager' then pre_memberidyominame end, ', ') account_manager,
    string_agg(case when localizedlabel = 'Lead BDM' then pre_memberidyominame end, ', ') lead_bdm,
    coalesce(pre_salesorderid,pre_opportunityid)  as activityguid
from [dbo].[pre_salesteammember] stm
left join optionsetmetadata os
    on stm.pre_rolecode = os.[option]
    and entityname = 'pre_salesteammember'  
group by coalesce(pre_salesorderid,pre_opportunityid)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This really helps the Pivot. But when using MAX, I lose data. It can happen that 1 ActivityGuid has 2 account managers, then they really need both to be mentionned, ideally like in my example. (there could also be 3 or 4 account managers)

Any help there?

Robbe

Comment: @RobbeVL: I see your point. I updated my answer with another query.